# How can I optimize this bit-packing function in C?

Tags: c, optimization, bit-manipulation, bit-packing

This code sample takes an arbitrarily large number of bytes as inputs, one at the time, and maps them to a table with 32 values [0,31]. To simplify the example I used mod 32. The >> 3 operation is equivalent to division by 8. In case it is not clear, the "q" loop counts to 5 because numbers from 0 to 31 only require 5-bits of resolution.

Can this be improved in terms of speed?

```
      uint8_t sto[10000]; 
      uint8_t srt[32] = {<32 values in total>};
      uint8_t t,q
      
      uint64_t loop,cr = 0;
      
      for(loop = 0; loop < 10000; loop++) { 
          t = srt[loop % 32];     
          for(q = 0; q < 5; q++) {
              if(t & (0x1 << (4 - q))) 
                  sto[cr >> 3] |= (0x1 << (7 - (cr % 8)));
              cr++;
            }
      }
```

Comment: Won't `cr` quickly become large enough that `(cr>>3) >= 32` and therefore `sto[cr >> 3]` is reading/writing past the end of the `sto` array and invoking undefined behavior?

Comment: You didn't initialize `sto` before reading it. This is UB. /// `t` is not used. Is some part missing? /// What is `largeNumber`? More missing code! /// How did you arrive to `1000000`? /// You ask us to optimize code, but there's so much questionable about the code. Can't optimize code that's not even correct!

Comment: That's not even addressing the real problem that real optmization is about taking a better overall approach, which requires knowledge of what is being achieved. This was not provided. /// Even if we limit ourselves to micro-optimizations, you didn't provided any information about the operating environment! What architecture do you want to optimize for?

Comment: I can think of many arbitrarily large numbers of bytes that will not fit in this buffer.

Comment: @affluentbarnburner, rather than a terse code snippet being described as a `function`, post a compliable function.

Comment: `if(srt[ord] & (0x1 << (4 - q))) sto[cr >> 3] |= (0x1 << (7 - (cr % 8)));` is just `sto[cr >> 3] |= (srt[ord] >> 4-q & 1) << 7-cr%8;`. But you should not be moving bits one by one. You can use shifts and bitwise operations to move multiple bits from `sto` into `srt` in groups. Ideally, `srt` would use a wider type than `uint8_t`, so more work could be done per array element.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including a test program with some sample data so that people answering can check their work.

Comment: Why does your text say the code takes an arbitrarily large number of bytes as inputs but the code uses the array with an arbitrarily large number of bytes, `sto`, as output, not input? The code is reading from `srt` (exactly 32 bytes) and writing to `sto` (an arbitrarily large number of bytes).

Comment: Point taken - I edited the code to correct some errors

Comment: The code simply repeatedly ORs a sequence of 160 bits (5•32) from `srt` into the bytes of `sto`. The primary optimization for that is clear: First reorganize the 160 bits from `srt` into contiguous bits, then OR those bits into `sto` using whole-word units for some word size—at least a byte (for maximally portable C), preferably more if `sto` can be aligned or if unaligned operations are available (depends on implementation details, available SIMD features, et cetera).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be reduced to simply:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    sto[i] |= bits[i % NBytes];
```

after doing some work to prepare `bits`. That loop can be unrolled, can be converted to units wider than `uint8_t`, can be converted to SIMD code, and can be parallelized. After a few of those, such as converting to wider units, it might stream at memory bandwidth, so further optimization might not be useful.

The work to prepare `bits` is to consolidate the bits from `srt` into a full bitmask:

```
#define NSrt    32          //  Number of elements in srt.
#define NBits   (NSrt*5)    //  Number of bits used from srt.
#define NBytes  (NBits/8)   //  Number of bytes used by NBits.

/*  Consolidate the bits of srt into bytes, processing eight elements of
    srt (i) and five elements of bits (j) per iteration.
*/
uint8_t bits[NBytes];
for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < NSrt; i += 8, j += 5)
{
    /*  Get five bits from each srt elements.  (b0 does not need to be
        masked because its high bits will be shifted out of the uint8_t
        span.)
    */
    uint8_t
        b0 = srt[i + 0],
        b1 = srt[i + 1] & 0x1f,
        b2 = srt[i + 2] & 0x1f,
        b3 = srt[i + 3] & 0x1f,
        b4 = srt[i + 4] & 0x1f,
        b5 = srt[i + 5] & 0x1f,
        b6 = srt[i + 6] & 0x1f,
        b7 = srt[i + 7] & 0x1f;

    //  Merge the five-bit segments into eight-bit units.
    bits[j + 0] = b0 << 3 | b1 >> 2;
    bits[j + 1] = b1 << 6 | b2 << 1 | b3 >> 4;
    bits[j + 2] = b3 << 4 | b4 >> 1;
    bits[j + 3] = b4 << 7 | b5 << 2 | b6 >> 3;
    bits[j + 4] = b6 << 5 | b7;
}
```

Comment: Very nice.  (Just a little more work if `NSrt%8 != 0`).

Answer (score 3):

Better optimization possible with larger code and a timing test harness.
Candidate simplifications (All minor).

**`t` never used.  Drop it**

Drop code `t = srt[loop % 32];`.

```
// t = srt[loop % 32];
```

@affluentbarnburner, did you mean `if(t & (0x1 << (4 - q)))` instead of `if(srt[ord] & (0x1 << (4 - q)))`?

**Form a *mask***

```
//for(q = 0; q < 5; q++) {
//  if(srt[ord] & (0x1 << (4 - q)))
for (unsigned mask = 1 << 4; mask; mask >>= 1) {
  if (srt[ord] & mask)
```

**Use `size_t` for array indexing**

```
  // uint64_t loop;
  size_t loop;
  for(loop = 0; loop < largeNumber; loop++) {
```

**Use byte and bit indexes rather than a combined one**

Separate (narrower) indexes *may* be faster.

```
  // uint64_t loop,cr = 0;
  size_t loop, cr_byte = 0;
  unsigned cr_bit_mask = 0x80;
  
  for(loop = 0; loop < largeNumber; loop++) { 
      // t = srt[loop % 32];     
      for (unsigned mask = 1 << 4; mask; mask >>= 1) {
          if(srt[ord] & mask) { 
              sto[cr_byte] |= cr_bit_mask;
          }
          cr_bit_mask >>= 1;
          if (cr_bit_mask == 0) {
              cr_bit_mask = 0x80;
              cr_byte++;
          }
        }
  }
```

Comment: the biggest optimization would be to vectorize it with SIMD and parallelize it

Comment: That approach is not part of standard C and since post was not tag for that, that idea is not mentioned.  Yet your interesting idea deserves your own answer.

Comment: I suspect there's some kind of `sto[cr_byte] |= ( (st[ord] & 0x1F) << ?) | temp; temp = (st[ord] & 0x1F) >> ?;` approach that can eliminate the inner loop; which might be fun.

Comment: @Brendan As I see it, one bit index has a period of 5 and another a period of 8.  For large array, might make sense, when `n >= 40`, to have 40 lines of code dealing with each group of 40 conversions.  Yet without a user supplied test harness, much work is theoretical.  Certainly more deserving if OP supplied more info, example and a true function.

Comment: @Brendan The compiler can probably unroll the inner loop if it notices a pattern with constants. Optimizations should focus on removing branches. For example you could perhaps per-calculate the various shifts, store them in temporary variables and then always unconditionally shift, although sometimes with zero.